# Trying to reference a static object thats name is stored as a field

Tags: aura

I am trying to get a static resource image to display but Am having troubles getting it to populate how I'd like it to. Here are the two approaches I've tried:

Hardcoding on the front end:

```
<div class="event-image" ><img style="max-height: 100px;" src="{'!$Resource.' + v.event.Program__r.Static_Resource_Name__c}"/></div>
```

Using Javascript to retrieve it (breaks code when line is reached):

```
   var sr = component.get('v.event').Program__r.Static_Resource_Name__c;
   console.log(sr);
   var img = $A.get('$Resource.' + sr);
   component.set('v.staticResource', img);
```

Comment: see this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16676/getting-a-static-resource-name-from-an-object-and-use-it-in-a-vf-page) for an idea - and [this VF doc ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_resource.htm)

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I think what you are trying to do "dynamically set the dot notation resource name" is not possible. I would suggest you store all the images within a single static resource (zip file). Then you can traverse down the directories and dynamically reference file names as seen here: [Dynamic reference to static resource in lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162939/dynamic-reference-to-static-resource-in-lightning-component)

Hope this helps!